# Why is Holi not much known in Southern India?

Tags: culture, festivals

Why is Holi not much known in Southern India? Did the festival come into being relatively late in North India?

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/45/why-do-people-celebrate-holi-why-do-they-throw-colored-powder-at-each-other  the question is on-topic

Comment: Lol good you reported. @SK And I haven't heard the expression.

Comment: Holi is actually mentioned by kalidasa in his poems so it's certainly a old festival.

Answer (score -1):

Holi is a popular Hindu festival celebrated in many parts of India, especially in North India. The festival is known for its colorful celebration, where people throw colored powder and water at each other. However, it is true that Holi is not as widely celebrated in Southern India as it is in the North.

There are several reasons for this. One reason is that Holi is traditionally a North Indian festival that has its roots in the Braj region of Uttar Pradesh, where Lord Krishna is said to have played Holi with his devotees. As a result, the festival has a stronger cultural and religious significance in North India.

Another reason for the lesser popularity of Holi in Southern India is that the region has its own traditional festivals that are more widely celebrated, such as Pongal, Onam, and Ugadi. These festivals have their own unique cultural and religious significance, and people in Southern India tend to focus more on these festivals rather than Holi.

It is worth noting that the history of Holi is not entirely clear, and its origins may date back to ancient times. Therefore, it is difficult to say whether the festival came into being relatively late in North India. Nonetheless, it is clear that the festival has a stronger cultural and religious significance in North India and is more widely celebrated in that region compared to Southern India.

For more information visit:
https://neutralpace.blogspot.com/2023/03/lets-color-world-with-joy-celebrating.html