# Does Holi celebration have a link to the Narasimha avatar?

Tags: vishnu, avatars, festivals, narasimha

In this [question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/45/why-do-people-celebrate-holi-why-do-they-throw-colored-powder-at-each-other) the reason for celebrating Holi was asked but the answer given is based on wikipedia which also says:

> The Holika bonfire and Holi signifies the celebration of the symbolic victory of good over evil, of Prahlada over Hiranyakashipu, and of the fire that burned Holika.

Considering that the **Holika dehan** or burning of Holika is celebrated on the eve of Holi, the logical conclusion would be that the next day is concerned with the celebration of her brother Hiranyakshipu's death at the hands of Lord **Narasimha.** But the **Narasimha Jayanti** is celebrated on Vaishakha Shukla Chaturdashi while Holi falls on Phalgun Purnima.

So my question is - **Is the festival of Holi related to the death of not just Holika but also Hiranyakshipu & do the scriptures mention an association between Narasimha and Holi?**

Comment: I think there was gap between death of holika and her brother, hiranyakashipu did all kind of wrong things with prahlad before holika act, which all failed. i'm pretty sure he kept doing it even after death of holika the avataran of Vishnu happened quite late, the act is hushed in scriptures but scripture do provide late dates for both celebrations.

Comment: @AnubhavJha ya i think so too but in the absence of any scriptural reference there would be no way to ascertain. It seems likely though that the two days celebrate one event signifying the victory of good over evil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sir your assumption may be right since many sites like this one ([Namaste.in](https://www.namaste.in/en/spiritual/573eb936b2f1dbd356a23367/57eb8d92bec71f6cb1a62d0e/detail/all-about-narasimha-dwadashi)) mention **Narasimha Dwadashi** also known as Govinda Dwadashi to be elebrated on twelfth day of the Shuklapaksha of Phalguna (February – March).

> Narasimha Dwadashi is the day when Lord Narasimha incarnated. Narasimha Dwadasi is observed on Falguna Shukla Dwadasi, the twelfth day in Shukla Paksha of Phalgun month. In 2019, Narasimha Dwadashi date is March 18, Monday. This day is also known as Govinda Dwadashi. Narasimha Dwadashi is dedicated to Lord Vishnu and it is celebrated by Hindus all over the world.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this @Viraj it does make sense now.

Comment: My pleasure Sir